# Quote Creation without Use of Opportunity Object?

Tags: opportunity, quote, developer-edition

On pressing Quote Object tab, we are not provided in creating a new record like any other Standard Object (See image 2), then why is there a option in create new Drop-down on the left corner (See image 1),on clicking Create new-Quote it displays "Insufficient  Privilege",Is there any other way to create a new Quote record without the use of opportunity Object.

1)
[image: 1]

2)
[image: 2]